# Error al compilar app Android con gradle desde linea de comandos

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

He creado una app Android básica desde Android Studio, con dos botones nada más, simple, sin modificar ningún archivo de configuración ni de compilación.

Estoy intentando aprender a usar Gradle desde línea de comandos, crear configuraciones de compilación, etc...

Al compilar la app desde Android Studio, se compila perfectamente, me genera el APK, me ejecuta en emulador... todo correcto.

Cuando voy al terminal de Android Studio, o desde el propio cmd de Windows, al lanzar **`gradlew.bat`** con cualquiera de sus opciones como **`gradlew.bat tasks`**, me salta siempre el siguiente error:

> Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example,
>     an unrecognized jvm option is used. Please refer to the user guide
>     chapter on the daemon at
>     https://docs.gradle.org/4.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html Please read
>     the following process output to find out more:
>
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

No entiendo a qué hace referencia el error en realidad. ¿Tiene que ver con la memoria del **`settings.gradle`**?

Dejo los ficheros gradle, por si sirven de ayuda:

**build.gradle (módulo)**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.devcodeg.android.geoquiz"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

**build.gradle (Proyecto)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

Comment: Haz caso de lo que te dice aquí: *`Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.`*  Intenta la ejecución con una de esas banderas y revisa el log de errores. Parece que el daemon está mal configurado.  O... [prueba esta solución simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20479940/5587982).  Puedes renombrar el directorio, por si acaso.

Comment: Prueba a ajecutar este comando para borrar el gradle y a ver si te lo soluciona:  rm -rf ~/.gradle/daemon/

Comment: He seguido las soluciones que indican en la página y lo he solucionado al final comentando la linea del **settings.gradle** -> `#org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m`. Gracias por la ayuda @A.Cedano @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia